# undefined is not an object.(evaluating 'PropTypes.number')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native and am trying to compile an old project with react-native v0.34.1. 
My project uses an older version of React, v15.3.2 to be exact. I am facing the below error.

[image]

Please, note that I am on the older version and I am aware of the prop-types package. But this is required if we use React v15.5 or above. Also can I know which is the exact file causing the problem from this red screen?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the component's code so we can have a look?

Shouldn't it be React.PropTypes.number?

Comment: No. It shouldn't. PropTypes has been removed from React. It is now a separate package.

Comment: "Please, note that I am on the older version and I am aware of the prop-types package" I interpreted this as meaning the OP is indeed using a version before the split. I might be mistaken though. Can you clarify please Saurabh?

Comment: `'use strict';

const React = require('react');
const {
  PropTypes
} = React;

const {
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  Platform
} = require('react-native');

const isEqual = require('lodash.isequal');

const Button = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    textStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
    disabledStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.string,
      PropTypes.node,
      PropTypes.element
    ]),
`

Comment: Ok, so you should be fine with using PropTypes directly. A `console.log(typeof React.PropTypes)` also gives you undefined?

Comment: This is my code in one of the componenets (third party). I do not know which of the components is exactly causing the problem.  "dependencies": {
    "apsl-react-native-button": "3.0.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "jail-monkey": "0.0.6",
    "jwt-decode": "2.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.13.1",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-mixin": "3.0.5",
    "react-native": "0.34.1",
This is my package.json

Comment: One question. Is there a way where I can Identify where from the error is coming / which package is causing the error ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't know React Native much. You know for sure it comes from a third party component? How so?